# How can I add each word in a .txt file to a list in Python?

Tags: python, file-io

I want to grab all the words from a .txt file and put them in a list with each word as an element of the list. The words are separated by line breaks in the .txt. My code so far is:

```
with open('words.txt', "r") as word_list:
    words = list(word_list.read())
```

However, this piece of code just puts each letter of the .txt as its own element in my list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open('words.txt', "r") as word_list:
    words = word_list.read().split(' ')
```

Comment: A superior solution if there are multiple words to a line.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of `.read()`:

```
words = list(word_list)
```

Without `.read()`, you're turning the file handle into a list, which gives you a list of lines. With `.read()`, you get a big list of characters.

Comment: D'oh I was sort of close. Thank you! One last thing, how can I get rid of the line break \n? Do I need to use regex?

Comment: @Biiiiiird: In that case, you can just use `word_list.read().split()`. If you don't pass an argument to `.split()`, it'll split on all of the whitespace it can find (newlines, spaces and tabs).

Answer (score 0):

See Here :

```
ashu='Hello World1'

 ashu.split()
```

This would split the words based on the spaces between them.

And if you want to split based on any other character instead of space you could do it like

```
ashu.split('YOUR CHARACTER')
```